# log4j2 change level of root logger at runtime?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Is it possible to change the root log level at runtime?

```
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

What I am looking for is to call some library API which would change the root log level from INFO to DEBUG and back. Without having to re-deploy the service.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Configurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html) class in `log4j-core` that exposes some basic functionality not available in Log4j2 API. What you are looking for is:

```java
Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```